# Что является и что не является передрягой

Tags: этимология

Можно ли какую-нибудь пустячную ситуацию, например легкое столкновение с человеком в пути, брошенный чей-то гневный взгляд, выражающий осуждение, разбитие стакана, назвать передрягой? Можно использовать сочетание "передряга с", если это чего-то, кого-то нет (электричество, свечи, доктора)? Корректно ли его употреблять вместо "перебоя"?

Comment: Почему "этимология"? Ведь происхождение слова не всегда раскрывает его современный смысл. И что, выражения "находиться в нехватке" не существует в рус. языке? Только в дефиците?

Comment: Употребляют не "в нехватке" (а уж "находиться" в ней вообще странно и не звучит), а просто "нехватка". Метка была правильная, "этимология" здесь вообще никаким боком.

Answer (score 1):

Передрягой называют сложную ситуацию, которую необходимо выруливать, часто бегая и решая что-либо (например, по инстанциям).

**передряга**

1) Затруднительное, тяжёлое, неприятное положение; неприятность.

*Жизненные, житейские передряги.


Переживать, выносить, выдерживать передряги.


Попасть в передрягу (передряги).*

2) обычно мн.: передряги, -дряг. Потрясение, сильное волнение, переживание.

*Душевные передряги.


Испытывать передряги.


Утомительные передряги опустошили его душу.


Таких передряг никому не пожелаю.*

3) обычно мн.: передряги, -дряг. Ссора, распря.

*Семейные передряги.


Не ввязывайтесь в передряги.


Передряги соседей по коммунальной квартире.*

Отсутствие электричества можно назвать передрягой, если пришлось ремонтировать что-то, бегать и искать мастера, договариваться с кем-то для решения проблемы. Передряга - это не пассивная ситуация.